# Hardware Configuration for Windows MultiPoint Server

Tags: windows, multipoint-server-2011

I've read every article on the Microsoft sites regarding Windows MultiPoint Server 11. I decided to go with a zero-client over USB configuration.

The problem is, we don't have distributors in our country for the zero client hardware available by DisplayLink and many others. We also don't have USB Capable LCDs.

I would like to try out a zero-client-over-USB by using a VGA to USB video adapter. It connects the LCD to the computer using the USB port, or a USB hub (provides drivers, can be used as an external standalone monitor, extended display, mirror and so on).

#### Configuration in Mind

1. WMS 2011 on a powerful computer.
2. Two internal/external powered USB hubs with 4 ports.
3. A USB keyboard, mouse, mic,
4. A VGA TO USB Adaptor.
   5- A Simple LCD.

#### Scenario

- Connect Hub 1 to USB port of the motherboard, with mouse, keyboard and Hub 2 attached to Hub 1
- Connect USB mouse, keyboard, USB VGA adapter to Hub 2 (we have a zero client terminal)
- Let's ask WMS to detect the terminal.

Will this work?

Note: Even the USB to VGA adapter is expensive, so I can't just buy it to try.